# Improving an unbiased estimator using the Rao-Blackwell theorem

Tags: self-study, estimation, unbiased-estimator, mathematical-statistics, umvue

Given data following a Bernoulli distribution $Y_1,...Y_n \sim B(1,p)$, we want to measure $\theta = \text{Var}(Y_1)$

I found this unbiased estimator $S^2 = \frac{\sum{(y_i-\bar{y}})^2}{n-1}$

I need to improve this estimator using the Rao-Blackwell theorem and determine if the new estimator is UMVUE for $\theta$.

I started with identifying the unbiased estimator sufficient statistics.

$$T(y)= \frac{\sum{(y_i-\bar{y}})^2}{n-1}$$
$$w(y)= \sum{(y_i-\bar{y}})^2$$

Therefore

$$T_1=E(T/W)=E(y_1/\sum{(y_i-\bar{y}})^2)$$

I'm not sure regarding the sufficient statistic ($w(y)$). Is it okay or am I supposed to just use $\sum{y_i}$

Next I tried to apply the Rao-Blackwell theorem, but I'm not sure about it at all

$$y_1/T(y)\sim B(1,P(y_1=1,\sum{(y_i-\bar{y})}^2=t))$$
$$\frac{P(y_1=1,\sum{(y_i-\bar{y})}^2=t)}{P(  \sum{(y_i-\bar{y}})^2=t)} = \frac{P(y_1=1)\cdot P(\sum{(y_i-\bar{y}})^2=t-1)}{\sigma^2 \cdot \chi^2_{n-1} }$$

I apologize if this is rubbish, it's just that I'm trying to figure out exactly how to go about this from what we were taught (or not, for that matter)

Comment: I am sorry to say that it is rubbish, perhaps because of typographical errors in the $\TeX$. To get you on the right track, please notice (1) an expression like "$\mathbb{E}[T|W]$" is a *conditional expectation,* not the expectation of the ratio $T/W$; and (2) writing $k$ for $\sum_i y_i$, it is an algebraic fact that $S^2=k(n-k)/[n(n-1)]$. With these in mind, you might get a lot out of re-reading the [Wikipedia article on Rao-Blackwellization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem) and applying its steps to your situation as you go along.